# How to get a 2D array of strings across the photon network in a Unity multi player game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, photon

I am trying to serialize a 2D array of strings to send over a network.

I have a couple ideas but I seem to be blocked by api or efficiency. I really don't want to serialize and send a small 2D array across a network  10 times a second when I only need it when I collide with something and ask for the information.

I have a list of items a player has in his cart. I want to make it okay to steal from that cart, so the other player has to be able to see what's in the cart.

If I use onphotonserializeview I thought I could convert the flatten the 2d array of strings into a 1D array of strings with a delimiter and stream.sendnext the delimited line and reconstitute on the other side, or some variation of that functionality.

```
public void serialize_merchandise_list() {


    int width = 0;
    int length = 0;

    while((width < cart_list_width) && (length < cart_list_width)) {          

        width++;

        if (width >= cart_list_width) {
            length++;
            width = 0;
        }

        // convert to bytes and then to string and append
           System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(merchandise_items[width, length]));

    }
}
```

But doing that unnecessarily is an operation time nightmare, I want it on demand.

I was going to do a punrpc but I can't get a return value or ref parameter. What is the best approach here?

I want:

1. collide with cart
2. do you want to steal from cart --> yes --> show list
3. else --> go on your way

Answer (score 1):

Afaik a one-dimensional array of strings would be [no problem for Photon](https://forum.photonengine.com/discussion/12991/sync-string-array).

So I guess you could just flatten the array and additionally send the second size - lets name it element size (in contrary to the first one - the element count) as parameters.

Like e.g. lets say your array looks like

```
string[,] array2D = new string[4,2]{{"a", "b"}, {"c","d"}, {"e","f"}, {"g","h"}};
```

Then you would know the second (elementSize) dimension using either hardcoded or [`GetLength(int)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.array.getlength)

```
var elementSize = array2D.GetLength(1);
```

and you would simply flatten the array using

```
string[] arrayFlat = array2D.Cast<string>().ToArray();
```

So you would send these two informations via photon (I don't know photon in detail) but afaik you can do this one time without having to send it continiously. The two parameters would be

```
int elementSize, string[] arrayFlat
```

in this case with the values

```
2, string[8]{"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"}
```

So together:

```
public void SendArray2D()
{
    int elementSize = array2D.GetLength(1);
    string[] arrayFlat = array2D.Cast<string>().ToArray();

    photonView.RPC(nameof(ReceiveArray2D), RpcTarget.All, elementSize, (object) arrayFlat);
}
```

---

Then on the receiver part you are getting

```
int elementSize = 2, string[] arrayFlat = string[8]{"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"}
```

and have to convert it back. You already know the second dimension `elementSize = 2` so in order to get also the first one you simply do

```
var elementCount = arrayFlat.Length / elementSize; // = 4
```

so you know the 2D array you will have to fill would be

```
string[,] array2D = new string[elementCount, elementSize]; // = 4,2
```

and then you can simply iterate it and do something like

```
for (var x = 0; x < elementCount; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < elementSize; y++)
    {
        array2D[x, y] = arrayFlat[x * elementSize + y];
    }
}
```

So together

```
[PunRpc]
public void ReceiveArray2D(int elementSize, string[] arrayFlat)
{
    var elementCount = arrayFlat.Length / elementSize;
    array2D = new string[elementCount, elementSize];
    for (var x = 0; x < elementCount; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < elementSize; y++)
        {
            array2D[x, y] = arrayFlat[x * elementSize + y];
        }
    }

    // Could also e.g. call some event like
    OnReceivedArray2D?.Invoke (array2D);
}

public event Action<string[,]> OnReceivedArray2D;
```

So you could attach listeners to the event via

```
reference.OnReceivedArray2D += SomeHandler;

private void SomeHandler(string [,])
{
    // ...
}
```

---

Or alternatively you could implement a class that stores your data in a flat array but lets you access it like if it would be a 2D array (in general a 2D array is anyway stored in memory as a flat one)

```
[Serializable]
public class SerializableArray2D
{
    public readonly string[] ArrayFlat;
    public readonly ElementSize;

    public SerializableArray2D(int elementSize, string[] arrayFlat)
    {
        ElementSize = elementSize;
        ArrayFlat = arrayFlat;
    }

    public SerializableArray2D(string[,] array2D) : this(array2D.GetLength(1), array2D.Cast<string>().ToArray()) { }

    public SerializableArray2D(int elementSize, int elementCount) : this(elementSize, new string[elementCount]){}

    public string this[int x, int y]
    {
        get { return ArrayFlat[x * ElementSize + y]; }
        set { ArrayFlat[x * ElementSize + y] = value; }
    }
}
```

usage would be e.g. Initialize it

```
var array2D = new string[4,2]{{"a", "b"}, {"c","d"}, {"e","f"}, {"g","h"}};
var serializableArray2D = new SerializableArray2D(array2D);
```

For accessing specific indices like in a 2D array

```
string example = serializableArray2D[1,1];
serializableArray2D[3,0] = "example";
```

For sending it

```
photonView.RPC(nameof(Receive), RpcTarget.All, serializableArray2D.ElementSize, (object)serializableArray2D.ArrayFlat);
```

And when receiving it

```
[PunRPC]
public void Receive(int elementSize, string[] arrayFlat)
{
    serializableArray2D = new SerializableArray2D(elementSize, arrayFlat);

    // Again e.g. call an event
    OnReceivedSerializableArray2D?.Invoke(serializableArray2D);
}

public event Action<SerializableArray2D> OnReceivedSerializableArray2D;
```

Comment: I appreciate the indepth response... my question was not how to flatten the array, but how do i get information from a sent punrpc if there is no return value ... i am only moderately strong in c# and i am trying to get information from the rpc... i was considering doing a pass by ref, but it doestn' seem like i can pass by reference.. so i cant modify outside the rpc nor can i return from the rpc...   i think im missing something because that seems like a logical use case

Comment: What I might try to do is either create an event or set a static variable in my context that would  work

Comment: Well it is up to you what you do e.g. within the `Receive` method ... and yes I would probably Invoke a `public event Action<string[,]> OnReceived;` or something like that and invoke it via `OnReceived?.Invoke(array2D);`